# How to improve performance of Enterprise Architect automation

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

Using C# adding if we try to create the diagram with 10000 elements it takes 20 minutes in enterprise architect to create the elements.Is there any way such that the performance can be increased such that the time duration for creating the elements can be decreased using C# addin.

Comment: Honestly, I'd ask if you are insane to create diagrams with 10k elements :-/

Comment: Totally agree with Thomas, the point of documenting is to show in a concise way how your software works. If you have a diagram with 10k elements, who is ever going to take the time to read it? Documenting jus to "have the documentation" and apply to organizational requirements isn't really *documenting* at all, as it fails to achieve the prupouse of documenting.

Answer (score 0):

You can create 10.000 elements in your model, no problem, but don't put them all on one diagram. That is just insanity as Thomas puts it.

I'm pretty sure you can't improve creating 10.000 elements in 20 minutes using the API.
The only alternative to improve the speed is to insert them into the database directly, but then you'll have to know **exactly** what you are doing. Not advisable unless you know the EA database structure like the back of your hand.

Hire a consultant if you are not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `Repository.EnableUIUpdates` to false while you're making bulk changes. It's also a good idea to make sure the diagram is closed with `Repository.CloseDiagram()`.

After you're done, set `EnableUIUpdates` back to true and, if you wish, call `Repository.OpenDiagram()`.

Comment: I once measured the difference between `EnableUIUpdates` being on/off and it came with no difference. It's a while ago, but I would not guess that this has been touched by any Sparxian since its introduction. Diagram updates don't go through. To make them visible you need to `ReloadDiagram`  in all cases. So I guess neither of these options will improve performance.